# Magento 2 Order ID missing from both both quote and sales_order tables

Tags: sales-order, quote, magento2.1.6

A client's site has been running for three years with order IDs being consistent with `sales_order` table's `entity_id`. A month ago, three order IDs were skipped all on the same day but hasn't happened again since.

I've read that missing/skipped order IDs is no cause for alarm though as I understand it, they should still appear in the quote tables. They were not there.

There weren't any changes to the step value, unless Magento can change them on its own and then revert back.

Is there any other reason for order IDs to get skipped?

Answer (score 1):

It is actually a Behavior of Magento that some of Order Are changed from Quote to Order but not Recorded in Order Table

Read Description of  this extension you will get answer

[FME Missing Orders](https://www.fmeextensions.com/find-missing-orders-extension-for-magento-2.html)

[Magento Community Questions](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Missing-Orders-in-Magento/td-p/136981)

[Another Link](https://www.reddit.com/r/Magento/comments/564mbg/customer_placed_the_order_successfully_but_its/)

Comment: All the reserved_order_id values from quote are also in sales_order. I've already tried searching for them in both tables but didn't find anything.

Comment: you can show you problem to this extension support the will tell you what actually problem is

Comment: Waqar did you guys manage to resolve this issue ?

Comment: there are extension avaible to resolve this issue you can check them